# Highchart 3D module is not working in angular 9.1.4

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using Highchart in my angular project, everything was working fine but when I update my angular cli to 9.1.4 the declaration start throwing following error ( error screenshot https://prnt.sc/scl6g8)

```
Argument of type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts")' is not
assignable to parameter of type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src")'.
Property 'ZAxis' is missing in type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts")' 
but required in type 'typeof import("/project/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts.src")'.ts(2345)
highcharts-3d.src.d.ts(19, 9): 'ZAxis' is declared here.
```

here are the import statement

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import highcharts3D from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d.src';
highcharts3D(Highcharts); // the above error is thrown on this line
```

Comment: There is a working demo and no error occurs. https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-cz3nc?file=/src/app/chart.component.ts try to change the `import highcharts3D from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d.src';` to `import * as Highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sd5122

Comment: This picture doesn't help to understand the problem which you are struggling to. Are you able to reproduce it using the above from my previous comment?

Answer (score 3):

try : import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts.src';

instead : import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer to this for better presenting your question/answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/3519504

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let Highcharts3d = require("highcharts/highcharts-3d");
let HighchartsExporting = require("highcharts/modules/exporting");
```

instead of import